# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, types

I am trying to give a conditional colour to a component in react if the type is like it will be green or dislike it will be red. This would work in javascript but with using typescript I am getting the error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ like: string; dislike: string; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ like: string; dislike: string; }'.

I am fairly new to typescript in react so I am not too sure how to solve this so any help would be great!

```
import React from "react";
    import {Text, View} from "react-native";
    
    import {styles} from "./styles";
    
    const COLORS = {
        like: '#00edad',
        dislike: '#ff006f',
    }
    
    const Choice = ({type} : {type : string}) => {
        const color = COLORS[type];
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {borderColor: color}]}>
                <Text style={[styles.text, {color}]}>{type}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    export default Choice;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `COLORS` object defines 2 key value pairs: `"like"` and `"dislike"`. If you try to access `COLORS["foobar"]`, it will give you a typescript error as it is not a defined key.

Similarly, your `type` is defined as a `string` and not constrained to only `"like"` or `"dislike"`. To constrain it, you need to only allow the `"like"` or `"dislike"` keys for it.

One way to do it is to say:

```
const Choice = ({type} : {type : "like" | "dislike" }) => {
```

A more robust way is to make the possible values based on your object.

```
const Choice = ({type} : {type : keyof typeof COLORS}) => {
```

As a side note, you React gives you generic types you can use it make you type expressions less cluttered:

```js
const Choice: React.FC<{type : keyof typeof COLORS}> = ({type}) => {
```